# Update Row 1 Column field from Row 2 column field

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do i update a table from the below scenario

TABLE: DIM_SCLASS

```
SCLASS_CODE | GL_CLASS_CODE | RPT_GRP | UW_YEAR_START| UW_YEAR_END
PA01        | 06            | P       |  1900        | 2017
PA01        | 06            | P       |  1900        | 2020
PA01        | 05            | V       |  2021        | 2500
```

My question:
1. How do I update the ROW 2 UW_YEAR_START where the value is taking from the ROW 1 UW_YEAR_END ?

Please find the above image on the scenario.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o5ir.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't it work?  Why Row 1 and Row 2? Why not Row 1 and Row 3?

Comment: The first row is the record in which i need to store the history data. the second row the UW_YEAR_START should be 2017 and UW_YEAR_end is 2020. As for third row the UW_YEAR_START is updated by taking the UW_YEAR_END from 2nd row + 1

Comment: it is very hard for me write post my question here as i not really good in drawing the table line here. I have all the data movement in excel but not sure how i put it here. Is it ok i email you my question

Comment: What are the conditions for when UW_YEAR_START should be the previous UW_YEAR_END vs. when it should be previous UW_YEAR_END+1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will update all rows. Add a `WHERE` clause to limit which rows get updated, if needed.

```
UPDATE d
SET d.UW_YEAR_START = LAG(d.UW_YEAR_END,1) OVER (ORDER BY d.UW_YEAR_END asc)
FROM DIM_SCLASS d
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a join.  Try something like this:

```
update DIM_SCLASS 
set r1.UW_YEAR_START = r2.UW_YEAR_START
FROM DIM_SCLASS r1
join DIM_SCLASS r2
on r1.SCLASS_CODE = r1.SCLASS_CODE -- YOU CAN USE 1 = 1 OR SOME OTHER CONDITION IF NECESSARY
where r1.ROW_NUMBER() = 1
AND r2.ROW_NUMBER() = 2;
```

Comment: Dear mtr.web do you have an email?

Comment: I try not to advertise my personal email, but depending on the reason...  Why do you ask?

Comment: so i can post my scenario to you and see whether you understand my exact question.

Comment: hi mtr.web based on your script, what if i have multiple row? i need to go to manually type in which row i need to update?